# Unable to Hide See All Records button from Sub Grid in UCI

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I am not able to hide 'See All Records' button from UCI, the button is not available in Ribbon Workbench. Please refer below screenshot for better understanding - Is there any other alternative?[image]
[image]

Currently I am working on MS Dynamics CRM online version 9.1. I have searched on internet but couldn't find something related to 'See all records' button on sub-grid. I have checked the forms for any setting while adding sub-grid, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have associated entity in the navigation then this icon will show up. Remove from form editor to remove this.

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/sub-grid-properties-legacy?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#show-list-behavior)

“Open Associated view” may be the right keyword to search.

**Update**:

I verified this in my environments (9.1.0.2251) - these options are not there.

But in our preview org (9.1.0.3010) - I can see it. No way to hide it.

Without associated entity in navigation:

[image]

With associated entity in navigataion:

[image]

Comment: There is no associated entity in form navigation, and if such is the case than it will display open associate view button and not see all records. If i click on this button it redirects me to the entity view page where I can see all the data and not associated records.

Comment: @AliasgarRajpiplawala which exact version you are in (from About page)? I dont see this option in my UCI apps

Comment: Probably you are above 9.1.0.3*** as I am seeing "see associated records" option similar to this in one of our preview orgs.. but in 9.1.0.2*** no such options..

Comment: @AliasgarRajpiplawala Ours is 9.1.0.2251 and those command bar items are not there.. may be another forced stuff on us by MS :) updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here My solution after I expensed a lot of time ..
Use Ribbon workbench , then select Home and look for NavigatetoHomepageGrid , button doesn't have an icon.

Hope It helps.

[NavigateToHomepageGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j47xZ.png)